# Shared session between 2 Laravel apps is not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-session

I have 2 Laravel applications

Application 1 is based on Laravel 5.4
Application 2 is based on Laravel 8

both apps connect to the same database and both share the same `APP_KEY` value

both apps have this in the .env file

`SESSION_DRIVER=database`

`SESSION_LIFETIME=120`

`SESSION_DOMAIN=.domain.com`

every time I open application 1, then application 2 logs out and when I login in application 2 then it's not shared with the application 1.

Can anybody help with this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sharing a session between 2 laravel applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25171414/sharing-a-session-between-2-laravel-applications)

Comment: no it doesn't, I already tried that.

Comment: Did you set `SESSION_COOKIE` to the same value in both apps? This determines the name of the session cookie, and by default is set to use the app name as part of the cookie and would therefore differ between apps.

Comment: They have the same value of `SESSION_COOKIE`

Comment: Maybe it's because app 1 is Laravel 5.4 and app 2 is Laravel 8?

Comment: That could be it, but since both have the same driver and app key I don't think so. Do you use the `EncryptCookies` middleware in both?

Comment: They both use  \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,

Comment: In that case, I think the problem could be because of the different versions or the cookie/domain configuration. Browsers are quite strict on not sending cookies to unauthorized domains. My only guess is to try setting `SESSION_DOMAIN` to just `domain.com` which would work with any subdomain and the base domain.

Comment: Did you managed to get it work?